# Excel 2010 grouping WITHOUT VBA

Tags: excel-2010, grouping, worksheet-function

I need help with grouping together responses in a workbook. I am using Excel 2010 and I have columnA with Categories 1,2,3,4,5 and 6. ColumnB has the responses A,B,C, and D from a pull-down list (A,B,C, and D are all defined in cells elsewhere in the spreadsheet and then referenced for the data validation drop-down list). Lets say the responses are 1-A,2-A,3-B,4-D,5-A,6-B. I want a formula in a different cell that will give me "1,2 and 5 are A; 3 and 6 are B; 4 is D" maybe not that cleanly but as close as possible to that. **I do NOT want answers that use VBA or macros**, even if it is not possible without them. I would just like to know if there is any way at all this could be done using any combination of formulas.

I have provided a sample with the necessary information towards the bottom using sample info such as school supplies and their availability (all the cell references will be easily transferable to my actual workbook due to the placement here). The dropdown list choices are defined starting in B294:B299, in case that is important (again, this is just to mirror the way it is setup in my actual file). Here is the link to the sample.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5qnLtwIDvK7TjV0TTJOSnNNRU0/view?usp=sharing
Please let me know what you can come up with! Thanks!

Comment: Is there only one response per category?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get what I think you want to work. I placed subcalculations in different columns in an effort to reuse evaluations and not to overwhelm you. If this is what you want, I strongly encourage you to attempt to understand what each formula is accomplishing and the overall logic.

[image: Grouping Spreadsheet]

The concept in my method is that each row needs to ultimately be aware of what was the last row above it that had the same response. Thus we can build on our way down the column. Column C tells us what row that is. Column D tells us what is the last row OVERALL with that same response. Column E determines how many instances of that response there are. Column E is used to determine if we should have a comma before an 'and'. Column F builds (as mentioned above) on the prior instance of that response such that the bottom-most row containing that response contains the total text for the response group. Column G appends the text from Column F if and only if that is the last row of the response group.

```
C2  =SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($B$1:$B1=B2)*ROW($B$1:$B1)))
D2  =SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($B$1:$B$7=B2)*ROW($B$1:$B$7)))
E2  =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,B2)
F2  =IF(C2=0,A2,INDEX($F$1:$F1,C2)&IF(ROW()=D2,IF(E2<3," and ",", and "),", ")&A2)
G2  =IF(ROW()=2,"",G1)&IF(ROW()=D2,F2&IF(E2>1," are "," is ")&B2&IF(ROW()=COUNTA($A$1:$A$7),"","; "),"")
```